# Order of Fermat number

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

A textbook exercise asks for the order of $F_{n−1}$ mod $F_n$ in $\left(\mathbb Z /F_n \mathbb Z \right)^\times $, i.e. the set of invertible elements in $ \mathbb Z /F_n \mathbb Z$.

The only answer I can think of is that, by Lagrange's theorem, this order should be a divisor of $\phi(F_n) $, but I do not seem to get any further.

Any hint towards a more precise answer would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Use *Cassini's identity*: $F_{n-1}F_{n+1} - F_n^2 = (-1)^n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt By OP's title, I assume $F_n$ means the Fermat numbers, not the Fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 0):

The order of $F_{n-1}$ mod $F_n$ is
$$\begin{cases}4 & \mbox{if } n=1 \\
2^{n+2} & \mbox{if } n \ge 2.
\end{cases}$$
A key to this exercise is that, for every $n \ge 1$, we have
$$F_{n-1}^{4} \equiv -4 \pmod{F_n}.$$

In order to prove this, let $e = 2^{2^{n-1}} = F_{n-1}-1$. We have
$$(e + 1)^4 = (e^2+2e+1)^2 \equiv (2e)^2=4e^2\equiv-4 \pmod{F_n=e^2+1}.$$

The rest is straightforward, as in the case of $n\ge 2$ we have
$$F_{n-1}^{2^{n+1}} = (F_{n-1}^4)^{2^{n-1}} \equiv (-4)^{2^{n-1}}
= 2^{2^n} \equiv -1 \pmod{F_n}.
$$
(In the case of $n = 1$, $F_0^4 = 3^4 \equiv -4 \equiv 1 \pmod {F_1=5}$, so the order is 4.)